# Why my below code giving java.lang.StackOverflowError exception?

Tags: java

I cant understand, why is my code giving `java.lang.StackOverflowError` exception? And can someone give a brief idea about why `java.lang.StackOverflowError` exception came?

```
public class BasicProg {

    BasicProg b = new BasicProg();

    int show() {

        return (true ? null : 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicProg b = new BasicProg();
        System.out.println(b.show());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your **BasicProg** Class object is created recursive. [here doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

A stack is the part of the memory. The local automatic variable is created on this stack and method arguments are passed. When a process starts, it get a default stack size which is fixed for each process.  In today's operating system, generally, the default stack size is 1 Mb, which is enough for most of the process. Under abnormal condition, the stack limit exceeds. This is known as stack overflow.
The two most common reason :

1. Infinite recursion

   ```
    int f(){ 
               g();
               }
               int g() {
               f(); 
               }
   ```
2. Allocating size greater than stack's limit

> ```
> public int test(){
>
> int x[10000000]; // array is too large 
>
> int y =0; //y's address exceeds the stack's limits, error
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting recursion because the constructor for the `basicProg` class is being called an infinite number of times.

```
public class basicProg {
   // everytime a new basicProg object is created, another one will
   // be created here, and so on...
   basicProg b = new basicProg();

    int show() {
        return (true ? null : 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        basicProg b = new basicProg();
        System.out.println(b.show());
   }
}
```

I don't know why your `basicProg` class even has that reference.  If you remove it, and make a few changes, your code should behave as expected:

```
public class BasicProg {
    public Integer show() {
        return (true ? null : 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicProg b = new BasicProg();
        Integer result = b.show();
        System.out.println(result == null ? "null" : result.toString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply

Answer (score 0):

You have a class member `b` which is instanciated when you create a new instance of `basicProg`. 
And that will call `new basicProg()` which created a new Instance and instantiate `b` and so on. Thats why you get the `StackOverflowError`.

BTW. Java naming convention says, that classnames should start with an uppercase character

Comment: Thank for your reply